# Use of Entry interface in java other than iterating over HashMap class objects

Tags: java, hashmap, javafx-8, key-value

Entry interface is used to iterate HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap classes objects with the help of entrySet() and keySet() methods.

Is there any other use of Entry interface?

Is there any class that implements Entry interface which can be used in place of Pair class (javafx.util.Pair) to store paired values?

Comment: It's not `Entry`.  It's `Map.Entry`.  It's part of the `Map` interface and is only really appropriate for use in `Map`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `Map.Entry`

The [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) interface has a nested interface, [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html). This interface holds a pair of objects, the key and the value for each entry in a map.

Java comes bundled with two concrete implementations, one mutable, one immutable, both nested in `AbstractMap`.

- [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)
- [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

Those concrete classes have indeed been used by some folks as a class for general use as a pairing, without any map involved. Ditto for `javafx.util.Pair`.

Generally better to define your own class, with clear naming  specific to the context of your problem domain.

## `record`

For immutable pairing in Java 16 and later, use the [*records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature. You merely need to declare the type and name of the member fields. The compiler implicitly creates constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Defining a custom class as a record makes it very easy to concisely define your own pair.

```
record Point ( int x , int y ) {}
record Coordinate( double latitude , double longitude ) {}
record Pixel( int horizontal , int vertical ) {}
record Assignment( UUID employeeId , String projectName ) {}
```

Note that you can declare a record locally, within a method, or nested or separate. Ditto for enum and interface in Java 16+.